# Rolify finder method returning empty array - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rolify

I'm trying to get one of [Rolify's Finder Methods](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/wiki/Usage#finders-methods) going (no. 3), but it is always returning an empty array.

**User model:**

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify

  has_many :forums, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**Forum model:**

```rb
class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base
  resourcify

  belongs_to :user

  def participants
    # Find all users with any role in the forum
    User.with_any_role :admin, { name: :moderator, resource: self }
  end
end
```

**Adding roles:**

```rb
user.add_role :admin, Forum.find(3)
```

**Testing roles:**

```
2.4.0 :043 > user.has_role? :admin, Forum.find(3)
  Role Load (21.9ms) SELECT ...
 => true
```

I have tried running `Forum.find(3).participants` and `User.with_any_role :admin, { name: :moderator, resource: Forum.find(3) }` from the console, and both return empty arrays, e.g:

```
2.4.0 :027 > Forum.find(3).participants
  Forum Load (21.9ms) SELECT ...
  User Load (28.7ms) SELECT ...
 => []
```

Is there something I am missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you add any role yet?

Comment: @bananaappletw I sure have.

Comment: What's command you type to add role?
Maybe I could help you debug it.

Comment: By follow your description. I think you add role to Forum class. Not the instance. Type this `User.with_any_roles :admin, { :name => :moderator, :resource => Forum }`. Let's see the result.

Comment: Added the command to add role and test into question.

Comment: I found it. You add `admin` role to Forum instance. But the command `User.with_any_role :admin, { name: :moderator, resource: self }` means either you have admin role without any instance or any moderator role to that specific instance.

Comment: Because `admin` role usually has more power. Admin can edit any instance. Moderator only can modify its own instance.

Comment: I see, you're right. Even running `User.with_any_role :moderator, { name: :admin, resource: Forum.find(3) }` (swapping the roles around) returns the user as expected. 

In that case, how am I meant to return all users with **either** a `:admin` **or** `:moderator` role for the Forum instance (e.g: `Forum.first`)?

Comment: Try this `User.with_any_role({name: :admin, resource: Forum.find(3)},{name: :moderator, resource: Forum.find(3)})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By tracing code [here](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/blob/master/lib/rolify/finders.rb#L21)
you can pass argument as string or hash.

```
User.with_any_role({name: :admin, resource: Forum.find(3)},{name: :moderator, resource: Forum.find(3)})
```

Will search all the users has either admin or moderator role for Forum instance which id is `3`.